# Mounting gym equipment to drywall frames with metal studs

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, metal

I have recently mounted a folding squat rack to dry wall framed with metal studs. Following another thread I mounted 2 2x6 horizontally across the length of the wall and attached to each stud with easy toggle and self tapping screw. Understand the primary risk is pull out strength however feels very sturdy. See pic below:

[image]

I want to mount some weight plate wall storage ( like pic below) in the area with the yellow circle however wanted to see if any advice on best way to do this securely. Was thinking of wedging in another 2x6 vertically between the existing horizontal boards and attaching to stud with easy toggle bolts? Any recommendations / advice are very welcome

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Most of the weight will be vertical, so would place a 2x6(or similar) on the floor first.  Mount the vertical 2x6 to the other 2x6s, with the vertical sitting on the floor 2x6.

Comment: If it's on a concrete floor, put a piece of heavy plastic between the 2x6 and the concrete, or put a small piece of pressure treated 2x6 on the concrete as a "footer", then put the non-treated vertical piece on top of that.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Regarding the horizontal 2x6 on the ground, this is just for the vertical 2x4 to rest on top of?